# Spring boot - Configuration files for h2 and mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I have the following files

```
application.yml
application-debug.yml
application-mysql.yml
```

Application-mysql.yml has the database connection and jpa database declarations and it all works fine if I set the active profile to mysql when launching. However if I set it to debug without mysql the h2 database loads. The application-debug.yml file contains the following, I thought I'd be able to just alter the active profile here to decide which database to use but it ignores the mysql active profile declaration ( or maybe it's a timing issue? )

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: mysql
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
```

To try and work around this I also created a schema-h2.sql file so that h2 wouldn't choke on some of the mysql specific queries when it ran but it looks like the h2 database just reads the schema.sql file regardless.

I'd love if someone could either explain clearly why neither of these approaches are working or suggest an alternative. I can just add mysql and debug to my active profiles but I want to figure out what I can and can't do with these files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below using properties

```
spring.profiles.include:
  - mysql
```

Or Programatically

```
SpringApplication.setAdditionalProfiles("mysql");
```

Comment: Works perfectly now, thanks! I'll have to look up the difference between the two